# I'm getting an error list index out of range

Tags: python

I'm reading 'Invent Your own Games with Python' and I'm trying to create a game that's in the book. Even though my code matches the code in the book I'm still getting an error:

```
File "/Users/Rocky/reverso.py", line 251, in <module>
    resetBoard(mainBoard)
  File "/Users/Rocky/reverso.py", line 27, in resetBoard
    board[x][y] = ' '
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
def resetBoard(board):
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            board[x][y] = ' ' #This is line 27


    board[3][3] = 'X'
    board[3][4] = 'O'
    board[4][3] = 'O'
    board[4][4] = 'X'

def getNewBoard():

    board = []
    for i in range(8):
        board.append([' '] * 8)

        return board



    while True: # line 248
            mainBoard = getNewBoard()
            resetBoard(mainBoard) # This is line 251
            playerTile, computerTile = enterPlayerTile()
            showHints = False
            turn = whoGoesFirst()
            print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
```

Comment: Please add the code for `getNewBoard`.

Comment: where should I add it

Comment: In the question. Click on [edit].

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why I'm getting the error.

Comment: look closely at your indentation. your `return board` line is actually _within_ your `for i in range(8)` loop, meaning that it returns after just one iteration, causing `mainBoard` to look like `[[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]`

Comment: in `getNewBoard` the `return` statement looks like it is indented into the `for` loop meaning it returns right after the first iteration.

Comment: thank you guys. yeah it was the indentation lol

Answer (score 0):

Return statement indentation in function `getNewBoard()` was incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize your list using this instead:

```
board = [[' ' for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]
```

It should initialize an 8x8 2d list (which will work without errors).

This code works:

```
def resetBoard(board):
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            board[y][x] = ' '


    board[3][3] = 'X'
    board[3][4] = 'O'
    board[4][3] = 'O'
    board[4][4] = 'X'

def getNewBoard():
    return [[' ' for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]

while True: # line 248
        mainBoard = getNewBoard()
        resetBoard(mainBoard) # This is line 251
        playerTile, computerTile = enterPlayerTile()
        showHints = False
        turn = whoGoesFirst()
        print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
```

Comment: `board = [[' ' * 8] * 8]` doesn't do what you seem to think it does, it makes a list of 8 strings that are each 8 spaces long, you cannot assign a character in a string so trying `board[3][3] = 'X'` raises an error.